# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed - drf_writable_nested

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Created a simple app that allows me to create clients and then also add a features list as a field (which has multiple options).

### models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Feature(models.Model):
    feature1 = models.BooleanField(default=None)
    feature2 = models.BooleanField(default=None)
    feature3 = models.BooleanField(default=None)

class Client(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    org_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    features = models.ManyToManyField(Feature, related_name='client_list')
```

### serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Client, Feature
from drf_writable_nested import WritableNestedModelSerializer

class featureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Feature
        fields = ('feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3')

class clientSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    features = featureSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id', 'client_name', 'org_id', 'date_created', 'features')
```

### python shell

```
>>> data = {'client_name': 'Test Client XYZ', 'org_id': '001', 'date_created': '2018-03-06', 'features': [{'feature1': True}, {'feature2': False}, {'Feature3': True},],}
>>> serializer = clientSerializer(data=data)
>>> serializer.is_valid()
True
>>> print(serializer)
clientSerializer(data={'client_name': 'Test Client XYZ', 'org_id': '001', 'date_created': '2018-03-06', 'features': [{'feature1': True}, {'feature2': False}, {'feature3': True}]}):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    client_name = CharField(max_length=200)
    org_id = CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = CharField(max_length=100)
    features = featureSerializer(many=True):
        feature1 = BooleanField(required=False)
        feature2 = BooleanField(required=False)
        feature3 = BooleanField(required=False)
>>> print(serializer.data)
{'client_name': 'Test Client XYZ', 'org_id': '001', 'date_created': '2018-03-06', 'features': [OrderedDict([('feature1', True)]), OrderedDict([('feature2', False)]), OrderedDict([('feature3', True)])]}
```

but when I actually go to save using:

```
>>> client = serializer.save()
```

I get the following error:

`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: client_feature.feature2`

I have no idea why this isn't saving. It seems to be generating an error on Feature2 for which I passed in a False value. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I was initially going to use the DRF API to create data but realized it does not support lists so I was unable to enter the features portion of a client. This is why I used the drf_writable_nested package.

Comment: when you're setting your features, can you put all in the same dict? like ```[{'feature1': True, 'feature2': False, 'feature3': True}]```. It looks like you're setting 3 features objects. I don't see why you would need a list here.

Comment: YES! It worked! I was following the documentation from drf_writable_nested (https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) who had it formatted with a dictionary for each item...weird.

Comment: hum i'm pretty sure they don't have the same class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, you're making a mistake about a doc https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested and your conception.

Here you have a class with three fields :

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    feature1 = models.BooleanField(default=None)
    feature2 = models.BooleanField(default=None)
    feature3 = models.BooleanField(default=None)
```

So when you were doing your instantiation, you were creating one feature with feature1 set, but not feature2 nor feature3, then a feature with feature2 set but not feature1 nor feature3 etc...

That's why I'm pretty sure in your  case you don't need list, as your object has all features in it.

In the example you pointed, is just declaring several sites.
For example is you had :

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_size=255)
```

You could have done :
`'features': [{'name': 'feature1'}, {'name': 'feature2'}, {'name': 'feature3'}...`]

It's important you understand that.

Here, I don't even know if you need a `ManyToMany` relation.

Comment: My goal was to eventually create a form where someone could create a client and there would be a list of 10 features (all boolean) which would be added to the client object when they submit. Would it be easier to just make a Feature class with just name and boolean field and then call it multiple times changing the name on the front-end?

Comment: Also the features are all predefined, the user would not be creating a custom feature.